# Tangent bundle of manifold with no odd dimensional sub-bundles

Tags: algebraic-topology, vector-bundles, characteristic-classes

First, a preliminary remark:

The Whitney sum of two vector bundles is orientable.
I saw this statement somewhere and was wondering if it's true. 
In particular, it's easy to show that $w_1(\xi\oplus\xi) = 0,$ which implies orientability for reasons outlined [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/450095/to-prove-a-vector-bundle-xi-is-orientable-iff-w-1-xi-0). 
However, is it true in general? Also, this seems like a somewhat complicated first way of getting orientability.

In Milnor-Stasheff $\S$9, they ask to show that $\gamma^n\oplus\gamma^n$ is orientable, where $\gamma^n$ is the canonical $n$-plane bundle over $G_n(\mathbb{R}^{\infty})$, and the above fact is only touched upon in the obstruction theory chapter much later in the book, so using it is somewhat unsatisfactory. The main question I have is about the following: there is a claim that if $2e(M)\not=0$ for a smooth orientable manifold $M$, then $\tau(M)$ has no odd-dimensional sub-bundles. It's clear that it has no orientable odd-dimensional sub-bundles, but I'm not sure about unorientable ones. Milnor and Stasheff remark that looking at a suitable $2$-fold covering of $M$ works, so maybe taking the standard one where each point is paired with a local orientation and taking the pullback of $\tau(M)$ under the covering map would work?

Comment: The statement that ξ⊕ξ is orientable can be seen elementary in terms of structure groups: If you use trivializations of ξ to write down trivializations of ξ⊕ξ, the matrices in GLn(ℝ) which describe the change of trivializations in overlapping trivializing neighborhoods will be block matrices with two blocks being the same and hence they have positive determinant. This means the structure group reduces to the subgroup of invertible matrices with positive determinant, which is one definition of orientability of vector bundles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The Whitney sum of two vector bundles is orientable.

This is certainly not true; for example, one of the vector bundles could be nonorientable and the other could be zero. What's true is that $w_1(V \oplus W) = w_1(V) + w_1(W)$, which shows that the sum of two copies of the *same* vector bundle is orientable, that the sum of two orientable bundles is orientable, etc.

> The main question I have is about the following: there is a claim that if $2e(M) \neq 0$ for a smooth orientable manifold $M$, then $\tau(M)$ has no odd-dimensional sub-bundles.

First use your argument for orientable odd-dimensional subbundles, then take the orientation double cover of a nonorientable odd-dimensional subbundle.

Comment: I realized after asking the first question that it was rather obviously false; thanks for the simple counterexample. I guess that the orientable double cover is an odd-dimensional orientable subbundle of the double cover of $M$, which is impossible since it's entirely contained in one of the copies of $M$.

Comment: @cats Not sure what you meant by" one of the copies of M" but the orientable double cover will be a connected manifold. One chooses the covering map,F, so that $F^*(\omega_1$(subbundle) = 0. This can be done for any element of $H^1(M;Z_2)$. Then the pull back of the subbundle is an orientable subbundle of the pull back of the tangent bundle of M. Its Euler class is also not zero because the top dimension Z-cohomology of an orientable manifold is isomorphic to the integers and a finite cover multiples the top cohomology by the degree of the cover.

Comment: @cats Also this argument works for any orientable n-plane bundle with non-zero Euler class over a compact n- manifold without boundary. It does not have to be the tangent bundle.

Comment: @JoeS the orientable double cover of a manifold is connected only when the manifold is not orientable, otherwise you get two disjoint copies. I'll think about what you wrote more closely but that's what i meant

Comment: @cats: yes, but I'm not taking the orientable double cover of the manifold. "Orientable double cover" is an operation you can perform on any vector bundle on a manifold (take the double cover corresponding to the top exterior power) and I'm applying this operation to a nonorientable odd-dimensional subbundle (so "nonorientable" here means that the result will be connected if the original manifold is connected).